# Edit/remove the action published by the app to the newsfeed

Tags: facebook, action, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to remove/edit the text shown in the picture which appears from the actions published by website. I went through the settings pages on the facebook dev page 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you can only remove published stories of apps that you own. IE, if you're using the open graph custom actions, whenever you publish an action, you get an action id back. You could then delete that action by referencing it with the action ID.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/#delete

Comment: I am trying to remove the text which says "Try Trinity College Kandy..." text after like and comment. It doesnt seem to be showing up on other applications.

Comment: @Eugene Abovsky, OP doesn't speak about OpenGraph actions but Post actions (see field `actions` in [`post` object documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/))

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this.

You can only remove the whole published story not alter already published one!

Comment: Are you sure cause it doesnt seem to be showing up on other applications. 
I am trying to remove the text which says "Try Trinity College Kandy..." text after like and comment. It doesnt seem to be showing up on other applications.

Comment: @Tharindu, sure they haven't because it's added by Application you used to publish that story. You not allowed to alter published stories, not with API and not with Facebook Site.